# How do I multiply 2 cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the algorithm for multiplying 2 cycles? My book doesnt give any example, so I do not have a clue. For example, how can I multiply $(12345)(94672)$? Or $(12)(13)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on whether you compose left-to-right or right-to-left.

Comment: @Ihf lets do it left to right. Just to see

Answer (score 2):

I'll show for $(12)(13)$ and it is the same for the other one. Start with $1$: $(12)(13)1=(12)3=3$ so we have $1 \rightarrow 3$. Now solve for $3$: $(12)(13)3=(12)1=2$ so $3 \rightarrow 2$ and finally $(12)(13)2=(12)2=1$ so $2 \rightarrow 1$ and your cycle is $(132)$.

Comment: I dont get this. How did you come up with $(12)(13)1=(12)3=3$

Comment: this one is right to left, the one shown by Hamed is left to right, if the cycles are not disjoint, order matters

Comment: @JennieDurham: Conventionally cycle notation is treated like a function and so applied from the left on an input. $(1\ 3)1 = 3$ because $(1\ 3)$ by definition maps $1$ to $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me do it for the first example: $(12345)(94672)$. Take $1$, then it goes to $2$ in first cycle and then $2$ goes to $9$ in second cycle. So until now you have $(1 9 \cdots)$. Now $9\xrightarrow{1}9\xrightarrow{2}4$, so $(194\cdots)$. Then $4\xrightarrow{1}5\xrightarrow{2}5$, so $(1945\cdots)$. $5\xrightarrow{1}1\xrightarrow{2}1$. So the first cycle is done $(1945)$.

Then take another element say $2$: $2\xrightarrow{1}3\xrightarrow{2}3$, so $(23\cdots)$. Next $3\xrightarrow{1}4\xrightarrow{2}6$, so $(236\cdots)$. Then $6\xrightarrow{1}6\xrightarrow{2}7$, so $(2367\cdots)$. Then $7\xrightarrow{1}7\xrightarrow{2}2$, so the second cycle is also done $(2367)$.

Is there anything remaining? No. So the final result is $(2367)(1945)$ or $(1945)(2367)$ doesn't matter in which order.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to visualize such things it is advisable to draw out the cycles as directed graphs and apply them one by one. Also, $(p\ q\ ...\ r)(r\ s\ ...\ t) = (p\ q\ ...\ r\ s\ ...\ t)$ if the two cycles only share $r$. (This assumes the standard convention that cycle notation represents a function on the underlying set of objects and that cycle product is exactly function composition.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to write the above as a product of disjoint cycles.

The way I've been taught to do this, is I start out with "1" and feed it onto the right side of the cycle:

$(12)(13)[1] \rightarrow (12)[3](13) \mathrm{\ (I\ get\ out\ a\ 3)} \rightarrow [3](12)(13)$

So "1" goes to "3" here. Now I feed "3" into the right side and get:

$(12)(13)[3] \rightarrow (12)[1](13) \rightarrow [2](12)(13)$

So "3" goes to "2" here. Now I feed "2" into the right side and get:

$(12)(13)[2] \rightarrow (12)[2](13) \rightarrow [1](12)(13)$

So "2" goes to "1" here. We're back at the beginning!

So we see that $1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1$, and so we write $(12)(13) = (132)$.

$\ $

So the process is, you feed a $1$ into the cycle on the right side. It spits out a number - that number, you feed it into the cycle, and see what next number you get out. You repeat this until you're back at $1$. If you've still got numbers left, you start with the lowest remaining number and do the same.

By this process, we get $(12345)(94762) = (1295)(3476)$.

EDIT: You can also do this by feeding stuff in from the right, it depends on how you've been taught to do this.